# Java (Netbeans) Print is producing a blank page

Tags: java, swing, printing

Any help is much appreciated. 
I have used this code to try and print the contents of a j Frame, however it only prints a blank page. I have tried adding various imports etc but I can't seem to get it to work. (My bracketing may be off as I have quickly removed any irrelevant code!)
Here is the code I have written:

```
package MenuPackage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SimplePrint extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Printable {
JFrame frameToPrint;

static JFrame SP = new SimplePrint();

public SimplePrint() {
    initComponents();
}

public SimplePrint(JFrame f){
    frameToPrint = f;

}


private void initComponents() {


private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    PrinterJob PJ   =   PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    //PageFormat PF   =   PJ.pageDialog(PJ.defaultPage());
    PJ.setPrintable((Printable) this);
    boolean doPrint = PJ.printDialog();

    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, doPrint);
    if(doPrint){
        try {
            PJ.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
       }
    }

}                                        


public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) 
    throws PrinterException {
    if (pageIndex > 0) {
      return(NO_SUCH_PAGE);
    } else {
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
      g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), pageFormat.getImageableY());
      // Turn off double buffering
      //componentToBePrinted.paint(g2d);
      //frameToPrint.print(g);
      SP.print(g);
      // Turn double buffering back on
      return(PAGE_EXISTS);
    }
  }
{




    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            SP.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}


}
```

Comment: please fix the code formatting for a better answer

Comment: Hi, I hope this helps

Comment: Printing components is always a pain in the code. Consider using `printAll` over `print`. Consider using something like Jasper Reports generally

Comment: Up-vote a million times @MadProgrammer's suggestion to use a report generating library. Don't re-invent the wheel, and don't make life harder than it needs to be.